How I can reproduce this floating animation effect?

It's an animation where you see food coming out of a pot and floating on top of the pot.

Create your pot and fruits, give them a Rigid Body physic, for the pot choose Shape > Mesh, give a different Mass to the pot and fruits (here 5 kg and 0.5 kg), in the Scene panel cut off the Gravity option, create a Force Field > Wind (here Strength > 6) and a Turbulence (here Strength > 30). Keyframe the wind strength if you want the object to float:


thx a lot I'll give it a try. Is there any way to make the food float in place once it's out of the jar without it going all over the place ? Thax for your help

yes, as I said, keyframe the force fields value, you can give a high strength at the beginning then lower down
